# Why bash on ubuntu on windows still using CRLF as line ending

Tags: vim

<s>I think the bash on Ubuntu on Windows should use LF as a line ending, but I'm wrong.It also seems to use CRLF as same as on Windows shell.When I am working on it, I got ^M problem from git diff like this:</s>

```
-            srv.save(name, atrbts);
+            if (gm.isMailboxEnable()) {^M
+                srv.createMailGroup(name, atrbts);^M
+            } else {^M
+                srv.save(name, atrbts);^M
+            }^M
```

<s>I know the problem is. I mean that the bash on Ubuntu on Windows should use LF as it line ending rather than CRLF, should it?</s>

#### Update:

I made a mistake that I opened a particular dos format file in the Bash and the Vim auto-detect it then using CRLF as a line ending. So the problem closed.

I am using `:set ff` command in Vim and its output is fileformat=dos then I found my mistake. I can use `dos2unix` command to repair this issue.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how is this problem related to `bash`. Maybe you're using a text-editor called `bash`?

Comment: HI, I am not using a text-editor called Bash.It is real Bash on Windows.There is [ABOUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) and [FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq)

Comment: Note that the choice of line endings is made by the application, not by the operating system.  (The operating system may provide a standard, but it is up to the application to follow it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats probably to ensure compatibility between `windows bash` and `text files` created on `Windows OS`. Thats why it uses `CRLF` as new line.

List of common representations:

```
LF: Unix and Unix-like systems (Linux, OS X, FreeBSD, Multics, AIX, Xenix, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS, and others.

CR+LF: Microsoft Windows, DOS (MS-DOS, PC DOS, etc.), DEC TOPS-10, RT-11, CP/M, MP/M, Atari TOS, OS/2, Symbian OS, Palm OS, Amstrad CPC, and most other early non-Unix and non-IBM OSes

CR: Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, ZX Spectrum, TRS-80, Apple II family, Oberon, the classic Mac OS up to version 9, MIT Lisp Machine and OS-9

RS: QNX pre-POSIX implementation

0x9B: Atari 8-bit machines using ATASCII variant of ASCII (155 in decimal)

LF+CR: Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output.
```

You can add `Windows Bash` to the list on `CR+LF`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying me. Maybe you are right. The problem is a compatibility one.I must say this is not very good design. From git view, I am working on the Ubuntu whereas I have to remember that I still working on the Windows ever and ever.